# Como concatenar uma variável a uma string que contém caracter de escape

Tags: python-3.x

Sou novato em Python, e estou tentando montar um servidor socket para troca de mensagens (Como um telnet) para comunicação com um cliente. O problema que estou enfrentando é que este cliente possui um protocolo próprio, e eu preciso fazer com que o server envie as mensagens de forma compatível.
Eu preciso que as mensagens sejam enviadas ao cliente no seguinte formato:

```
    b'\x01\x08\x00Testando'
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo produzir o sinal '\' como deve ser, o segundo byte '\x08' deve ser de acordo com o tamanho da mensagem (Em hexadecimal) e para isso eu criei uma variável 'h' para calcular, e depois fazer a concatenação na string, mas não consigo concatenar, o Python me retorna erros.
Eu tentei concatenar das seguintes formas:

```
    '\x01\x'+h+'\x00'   # Deu erro.
    r'\x01\x'+h+'\x00'   # Não deu erro, mas ficou com duas barras '\\'.
    str('\x01\x'+h+'\x00')   # Outra vez um erro.
```

Não funcionou, se eu colocar dois sinais de '\', aí ele aceita, porém o envio ao cliente fica errado, contendo dois sinais e ele não aceita esse formato.

```
    b'\\x01\\x08\\x00Testando'   # O cliente não aceita assim.
```

Tentei usar o unicode '\u', mas ele me resultou na mesma sequencia acima, com dois sinais de '\'.
Reparei que esse erro só ocorre quando eu tento concatenar a string com a variável, se eu colocar o valor manualmente como no primeiro código apresentado, ele aceita sem problemas, mas como eu preciso fazer isso dinamicamente torna-se inviável.
Se eu concatenar a variável sem o sinal de '\' no byte anterior à ela, o Python não acusa erros, mas se eu colocar o sinal ele não aceita.

```
    '\x01x'+h+'\x00'   # Aceitou sem problemas, porém faltando o sinal.
```

Outra coisa que reparei é que ele exige que após o x, tenham dois caracteres, se tiver menos ele acusa erro também, por exemplo:

```
    '\x01\x0\x00Testando'   # Faltando uma casa no segundo byte da erro.
    '\x01\x08\x00Testando'   # Feito manualmente, funciona perfeito.
```

Para enviar essa string ao cliente, o socket exige que seja em bytes, e eu testei duas formas:

```
    b'\x01\x'+h+'\x00'
    bytes('\x01\x'+h+'\x00', 'iso-8859-1')
```

Tentei com e sem codificação iso.
Eu gostaria de saber se alguém tem ideia do que eu possa fazer para conseguir montar a string no formato que é exigido pelo cliente.
Ah, a codificação com a qual o cliente trabalha é 'iso-8859-1'.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Você tentou converter o *h* em byte antes de concatenar? (com o método [*bytes.fromhex()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex))? Tipo: `b'\x01' + bytes.fromhex(h) + b'\x00'`

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está acontecendo porque os dados não são uma string e sim uma sequência de bytes.

Para concatenar a variável *h* a essa sequência, é necessário converter a string hexadecimal para o tipo *byte* com o método [*bytes.fromhex()*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex), e depois fazer a concatenação.

Exemplo:

```
h = '0c'

res = b'\x01' + bytes.fromhex(h) + b'\x00' # Converte em byte e concatena    
res
b'\x01\x0c\x00' # saída
```